# recursive locks

Tags: data-structures

Is there a use case for recursive locks? Is there a scenario that absolutely requires recursive locking.

Seems to be complicated and dangerous to use. I can see that we may avoid deadlocks (provided the lock stack doesn't overflow) but don't we want to catch such problems.

Maybe I'm missing something here. Any pointers are appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I like the title of this Blog entry:

[Recursive locks will kill you](http://www.fieryrobot.com/blog/2008/10/14/recursive-locks-will-kill-you/)

I also like this quote:

> http://www.thinkingparallel.com/2006/09/27/recursive-locks-a-blessing-or-a-curse/
>
> Don’t use recursive mutexes. It’s akin to sex with used condoms.

Finally, here's an extremely interesting article about how recursive locks got into Posix pthreads in the first place:

> http://groups.google.com/group/comp.programming.threads/msg/d835f2f6ef8aed99?hl=en&pli=1
>
> Recursive mutexes are a hack. There's nothing wrong with using them,
>   but they're a crutch. Got a broken leg or library? Fine, use the
>   crutch. But at least be aware that you're using a crutch, and why; and
>   once in a while check out the leg (or library) to be sure you still
>   need the crutch. And if it's not healing up, go see a doctor, because
>   that's just not OK. When you have no choice, there's no shame in using
>   a crutch... but you can't run very well on a crutch, and you'll also
>   be slowing down anyone who depends on you.
>
> Recursive mutexes can be a great tool for prototyping thread support
>   in an existing library, exactly because it lets you defer the hard
>   part: the call path and data dependency analysis of the library. But
>   for that same reason, always remember that you're not DONE until
>   they're all gone, so you can produce a library you're proud of, that
>   won't unnecessarily contrain the concurrency of the entire
>   application.

Comment: Thanks. The crutch thing makes sense I stumbled into this fixing some legacy "inherited" code.