# Best practices for concurrent C++ applications

Tags: c++, multithreading, design-patterns, concurrency

I have some questions regarding software design aspects for designing concurrent C++ applications. I have some hihger-level question (I know the basics like 'what is a lock/mutex/condition variable' etc).

**Locking in function hierarchies**

Assume that some function `func` operates on some object `obj`. It is necessary during these operations to hold a lock (which might be a member variable of `obj`). Now assume that
`func` calls a subfunction `func_2` while it holds the lock. Now `func_2` operates on an object which is already locked. However, what if I also want to call `func_2` from somewhere else without holding the lock? Should `func_2` lock `obj` or should it not? I see 3 possibilites:

1. I could pass a `bool` to `func_2` indicating whether ot not locking is required.
   This seems to introduce a lot of boilerplate code though.
2. I could use a recursive lock and just always lock `obj` in `func_2`. Recursive locks
   seem to
   be problematic though, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8720825/1255016).
3. I could assume that every caller of `func_2` holds the lock already. I would have
   to document this and perhaps enforce this (at least in debugging mode). Is
   it reasonable to have functions make assumptions regarding which locks are / are not
   held by the calling thread? More generally, how do I decide from a design perspective
   which function should lock `Obj` and which should assume that it is already locked?

Do you have a recommendation for this?

**Exposing a lock/mutex**

So far I am using a method returning a `Mutex&` which I supply to an RAII `Lock`. I think that if I were to use C++11 it would be more idiot proof to return a `Lock` directly and to overload the move constructor. But this is not possible in C++03. Still, is there a differnt strategy?
Is it generally recommended to expose a mutex or should this rather be avoided?

**Object hierarchies**

Assume that I have a Document consisting of multiple Pages. This document might be accessed in the following ways:

1. The user interacts by changing/deleting/inserting/copying pages
2. Threads rerender Pages which become visible / have changed / etc.

The obvious way would be a big lock for the Document which every thread has to hold while accessing the document. This has the distinct disadvantage that the rendering threads are essentially working consecutively even if they access different pages. I have two solutions in mind:

1. Use a read-write mutex. Upon modifying the document the thread has to have write access
   while the rerendering threads only need read access.
2. Use a lock for each Page plus one for the Document. Rerendering threads hold the Page
   lock. The user thread acquires the Page lock when changing a Page and in addition the
   Document lock when it changes the structure of the Document.
   It might be necessary to hold multiple Page locks if the user wants to for instance swap
   two Pages. In this case I believe there has to be a fixed locking order.

How do these approaches compare regarding code complexity / execution time? What would you recommend?

**Locking across threads**

Consider again the scenario from the last point. Assume that there is some affinity regarding tasks and threads. More to the point, some functions are required to be called solely from a particular thread (if you must know I am using gtk and it is required that any interaction with gtk has to be performed from a single thread.). The approach seems to be to add a callback to be processed by the *correct* thread. However, what happens if I require a lock to be held during the entire operation? Should I pass the (held) lock across threads (this seems like an anti-pattern to me)?

**Single thread support**

To hunt down bugs I would like to have a single threaded mode. Assume that I have a Scheduler
which gets passed a `Runnable` class instance with a `run` method. Normally the Scheduler acts as a Threadpool. It would notify some idle thread and pass it the instance to be processed. I had the naive idea to make the Scheduler just call the `run` method itself. This does not work however since the calling function might hold locks which the `Runnable` needs to lock as well leading to a deadlock. Is there some simple way to avoid this situation? I am tempted to pass a `bool` to the lock indicating whether or not the lock is merely a dummy and should do absolutely nothing. But this could just introduce multi-threaded problems (violated invariants) into a single threaded environment... Is there some simple way to get a Scheduler to switch to single threaded mode?

Those are quite some problems and it took me a while to write everything down :)
I would very much appreciate your help though. Recommendations for literature would
also be welcome.

Comment: 'Should I pass the (held) lock across threads (this seems like an anti-pattern to me)' - not really, no.  It's not uncommon to signal/queue objects that have internal synchro objects between threads.

Comment: Perhaps you could get some answers if you split your question into several independent ones. Also note that asking for recommendations is against the current SO practice and will likely be quickly put "on hold", just like this one. You might have better chances here with questions that are not that long and may have a definitely correct answer (so that a winning response can be selected).

Comment: Read [C++ Concurrency in action](http://www.manning.com/williams/), written by the father of [boost::thread](http://www.boost.org/libs/thread/), which has been, more or less, duplicated in C++11