# Locking in function hierarchies

Tags: c++, multithreading, locking, mutex

I am currently running into some design problems regarding concurrent programming in C++
and I was wondering if you could help me out:

Assume that some function `func` operates on some object `obj`. It is necessary during these operations to hold a lock (which might be a member variable of `obj`). Now assume that
`func` calls a subfunction `func_2` while it holds the lock. Now `func_2` operates on an object which is already locked. However, what if I also want to call `func_2` from somewhere else without holding the lock? Should `func_2` lock `obj` or should it not? I see 3 possibilites:

1. I could pass a `bool` to `func_2` indicating whether ot not locking is required.
   This seems to introduce a lot of boilerplate code though.
2. I could use a recursive lock and just always lock `obj` in `func_2`. Recursive locks
   seem to
   be problematic though, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8720825/1255016).
3. I could assume that every caller of `func_2` holds the lock already. I would have
   to document this and perhaps enforce this (at least in debugging mode). Is
   it reasonable to have functions make assumptions regarding which locks are / are not
   held by the calling thread? More generally, how do I decide from a design perspective
   whether a function should lock `Obj` and which should assume that it is already locked?
   (Obviously if a function assumes that certain locks are held then it can only call
   functions which make at least equally strong assumptions but apart from that?)

My question is the following: Which one of these approaches is used in practice and why?

Thanks in advance

hfhc2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Passing an indicator whether to lock or not:**

You give the the  lock choice to the caller. This is error prone:

- the caller might not do the right choice
- the caller needs to know implementation details about your object, thus breaking the principle of encapsulation
- the caller needs access to the mutex
- If you have several objects, you eventually facilitate conditions for deadlocks

**2. recursive lock:**

You already highlighted the issue.

**3. Pass locking responsibility to caller:**

Among the different alternatives that you propose, this seems the most consistent.  On contrary of 1, ou don't give the choice, but you pass complete responsibility for locking.  It's part of the contract for using func_2.

You could even assert if a lock is set on the object, to prevent mistakes (although teh check wold be limited because you would not necessarily be in position to verivy who owns the lock).

**4.Reconsider your design:**

If you need to ensure in func_2 that the object is locked, it means that you have a critical section therein that you must protect.  There are chances that both functions need to lock because they perform some lower level operations on obj and need to prevent data races on an instable state of the object.

I'd strongly advidse to look if it would be feasible to extract these lower-level  routines from both func and func_2, and encapsulated them in simpler primitive functions on obj.  This approach could also contribute to locking for shorter sequences thus increasing opportunity for real concurrency.

Comment: Just as an addition: I am on occasion using callbacks within an observer pattern, for instance whenever data has changed. During the callbacks I would like to have the object in a consistent state which would require holding a lock...

Comment: Excellent question of its own !  The observer will be called within the modifying thread. So you'll need to manage concurrency of observer (separate data structure, distinct lock) which is best candidate then for causing either concurrency bottleneck, or worse, if you hold the lock while observer is called, deadlocks.  Suggestions: have an asynchronously managed observer (reduce bottlneck situation) ? or make a consistent copy of the needed values, release the lock and pass the values to observer ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, just as another follow-up. I recently read [the API documentation of glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.42/glib-Asynchronous-Queues.html), in particular the section about message-passing queues. I found that most functions operating on these queues come in two variants, named `function` and `function_unlocked`. The idea is that if a programmer wants to execute a single operation, like popping from the queue this can be done using `g_async_queue_pop()`. The function automatically takes care of the locking/unlocking of the queue. However, if the programmer wants to for instance pop two elements without interruption, the following sequence may be used:

```
GAsyncQueue *queue = g_async_queue_new();

// ...

g_async_queue_lock(queue);

g_async_queue_pop_unlocked(queue);
g_async_queue_pop_unlocked(queue);

g_async_queue_unlock(queue);
```

This resembles my third approach. It is also the case that assumptions regarding the state of certain locks are made, they are required by the API and required to be documented.